# Can split second be used to block damage prevention effects?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My friend plays a stupid amount of prevent all damage instants. If I attack, and use something with [split second](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/~/magic%3a-the-gathering%3a-split-second), can he still use his prevent all damage? Or with split second ending the stack, is he unable to do anything except block?

Comment: Split second is very handy against somebody who plays a lot of counter spells

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

Note the text of split second:

> Split second *(**As long as this spell is on the stack**, players can't cast spells or activate abilities that aren't mana abilities.)*

Split second only prevents casting spells and activating abilities while the split-second spell itself is on the stack. This means no player may take an action in between casting the spells and resolution. After that spell resolves, however, you'll still pass priority around normally (meaning your friend now gets to play other spells or abilities) before going on to the next part of the turn.

If you want to prevent your opponent from casting spells, you'll need countermagic or a [Silence](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Silence) effect. Try [Grand Abolisher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grand%20Abolisher) if you want to keep your opponent from messing with your attack phase.

Alternatively, you can play cards that cancel out the effects of his spells — e.g. [Skull Crack](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skull%20Crack) or [Leyline of Punishment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20Punishment) against damage-prevention effects.

Comment: Re "This means no player may take an action in between casting the spells and resolution", note that Triggered Abilities can still be added to the stack, and Special Actions can still be performed.

Comment: Alright figured it would be too good to be true. I guess ill have to sideboard some skull cracks to deal with it. With 12 prevent all damage, (fog, darkness, and holy day) ill only need one strong attack. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Split second only prevents casting spells and activating abilities while the split-second spell itself is on the stack.

If you were to cast a split-second spell after blockers are declared, he wouldn't be able to respond to it with his instant. But as soon as your split-second spell resolves, both players are again given the chance to cast a spell. He could cast his then.